# Are exact-width integers in Cython actually platform dependent?

Tags: c, integer, cython, portability, fixed-width

In Cython one can use exact-width integral types by importing them from `stdint`, e.g.

```
from libc.stdint cimport int32_t
```

Looking through [stdint.pxd](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdint.pxd), we see that `int32_t` is defined as

```
cdef extern from "<stdint.h>" nogil:
    ...
    ctypedef signed int int32_t
```

Does this mean that if I use `int32_t` in my Cython code, this type is just an alias for `signed int` (`int`), which might in fact be [only 16 bits wide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types)?

The issue is the same for all the other integral types.

Comment: Can you name any architecture that is officially supported by Cython that is not ILP32 or LP64?

Comment: I don't know. Are there a list/statement of what platforms Cython supports?

Comment: @jmd_dk Couldn't find a prominent one in the docs, but the `MANYLINUX_IMAGES` in the [Makefile](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Makefile) gives a hint: i686, x86_64, aarch64.

Comment: Note that POSIX requires `int` to be at least 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be fine.

The typedefs that are really used come from the C stdint.h header, which are almost certainly right.

The Cython typedef

```
ctypedef signed int int32_t
```

Is really just so that Cython understands that the type is an integer and that it's signed. It isn't what's actually used in the generated C code. Since it's in a `cdef extern` block it's telling Cython "a typedef like this exists" rather than acting as the real definition.

Comment: Thanks, that put some peace to my mind. But I still find it odd. What would happen if the typedef was replaced by e.g. `ctypedef long long int int32_t` or even `ctypedef float int32_t`? Exactly what information within the typedef is used by Cython, and why can't it just take the entire information from `stdint.h`?

Comment: The information that Cython uses is just the signedness and the fact that it's an integer type (so you can do integer operations on it like +/*-). Cython has no ability to read C files like stdint.h (and I don't think there's any guarantee that the file really exists). So the problem is you have to tell Cython something about the typedef even if it's not completely true

Comment: The `long long int` version would probably make no difference. The `float` version would (there's some places where floats are treated differently to integers) but maybe not a huge difference. Maybe division by 0 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

On a platform where `signed int` is not 32bit wide, `int32_t` would be `typedef`'ed to a type that actually *is* 32bit wide.

If no such type is available -- e.g. on a platform where the maximum int width is 16, or where all ints are 64bit, or where `CHAR_BIT` does not equal 8 -- the exact-width types would not be defined. (Yes, the exact-width types are *optional*. That is why there are least-width types as well.)

Disclaimer: This is speaking from a purely C perspective. I have no experience with Cython whatsoever. But it would be *very* surprising (and a bug) if this would not be covered adequately in Cython as well.

And as @JörgWMittag points out in his comment, the alternative is of course to simply not *support* any platform where `signed int` isn't 32 bit wide.

Comment: "On a platform where `signed int` is not 32bit wide, `int32_t` would be `typedef`'ed to a type that actually *is* 32bit wide." How do you see that, given the Cython implementation `ctypedef signed int int32_t`? I know how it works in C, my question is Cython specific.

Comment: @jmd_dk: Then such other platforms are not supported. But I daresay you would realize that in a much "louder" way than your exact-width type silently being the wrong size. Probably during installation of Cython, or as an error message when starting up the compiler.

Comment: Sure, I was just wandering whether to make an effort out of making my Cython program portable (here wrt. integral widths). But if Cython itself doesn't do so, there's no point in me even attempting.

Comment: @jmd_dk Well, if ypu are using int32_t, you are guaranteed it will be 32bit *even if* Cython ever gets ported to a different platform, because then they *will have to* get this right. ;-)